# Issue validating self signed certificate: handshake_failure received

Tags: ssl, quickfixj

I am using quickfix to validate server's certificate and get fatal handshake_failure.

This is how it looks to me:

- Initial handshake is initiated
- The client connects.
- The server accepts.
- A TLS handshake occurs during which:

  o    Cipher suites are successfully negotiated.

  o    The client verifies the server certificate

  o    The server arbitrarily closes the socket.( SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify <-- This however looks like a clean closure.)

  o    The client is left hanging

Can someone take a look at it. Please.

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false 
Allow legacy hello messages: true 
Is initial handshake: true 
Is secure renegotiation: false 
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3 
%% No cached client session 
..
..
*** ClientHello, TLSv1 
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1468991703 bytes = { 167, 140, 147, 81, 176, 169, 230, 45, 229, 147, 246, 106, 201, 127, 79, 194, 88, 63, 1, 91, 34, 184, 35, 49, 119, 31, 227, 157 } 
..
..
ISocketConnector-0, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149 
MINA session created for FIX.4.4:ZZZZZ->YYYY: local=/X.X.X.X:XXXXXX, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketSessionImpl, remote=/XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:YYYYY [quickfix.mina.initiator.InitiatorIoHandler:50]
SocketConnectorIoProcessor-0.0, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81 
*** ServerHello, TLSv1 
..
..
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA 
Compression Method: 0 
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty> 
%% Initialized:  [Session-1885, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA] 
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA 
SocketConnectorIoProcessor-0.0, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 3224 
*** Certificate chain 
chain [0] = [ 
Version: V3 
..
..
..
..

READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 14 
*** CertificateRequest 
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA 
Cert Authorities: 
<Empty> 
*** ServerHelloDone 
*** Certificate chain 
*** 
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1 
WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 141 
SESSION KEYGEN: 
 PreMaster Secret: 
..
..
CONNECTION KEYGEN: 
Client Nonce: 
..
..
Server Nonce: 
..
..
Master Secret: 
..
..
Client MAC write Secret: 
..
..                                  
Server MAC write Secret: 
..
..
Client write key: 
...
Server write key: 
..
Client write IV: 
..
Server write IV: 
..
..
WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1 
*** Finished 
verify_data:  { 85, 227, 34, 74, 171, 223, 226, 95, 232, 234, 118, 50 } 

WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48 
READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2 
RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure 
fatal: engine already closedRethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure 
called closeOutbound() 
closeOutboundInternal() 
SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify 
WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32 
called closeInbound() 
fatal: engine already closedRethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack? 
called closeOutbound() 
closeOutboundInternal()
```

Comment: server sees: SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> *** CertificateRequest
> ```

The server wants a client certificate but the client does not send any. Therefore the server closes the connection with a a handshake_failure alert.

Comment: can this be because cert authorities : empty? FYI we are using server's self signed cert

Comment: @fiddle: There can be various reasons why the client does not send a certificate. For example the client might not have a certificate configured for sending or the client might have no support for client certificates at all. Hard to tell from this few information. And it is irrelevant for this if the server certificate is self-signed or not. Only the missing client certificate matters for this problem.

Comment: I see my .jks file has only one entry for the servers intermediate certificate. Do i need to add my client cert in that or some place else? If then, then how? could you please guide.

Comment: @fiddle: I'm not familiar with the tools and libraries you use. All I can say is that the server is requesting a client certificate and the client is not sending one. I don't know if there even is a way with your client to use client certificates.